# How do I write the _spec function for my custom API?

Tags: api, developer, civix

When I run...

```
civix generate:api foo bar
```

...civix generates the following code:

```
function _civicrm_api3_foo_Bar_spec(&$spec) {
  $spec['magicword']['api.required'] = 1;
}
```

From this example, I can see how to make fields *required* when writing APIs. Cool. But *what else* can I do with this `$spec` array? Can I set default values? Can I indicate what *type* of value to accept? Can I specify an array of valid values? Or a regex pattern to test for validity?

Really, I'm not looking for answers to those specific questions, **I'm looking for a comprehensive list** of *everything* I can type in place of `'api.required'` above (and an explanation of how each one works).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a bit of research I added documentation which explains how to write `_spec` functions:

https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/framework/api-architecture/#spec

Answer (score 1):

As per https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/api/v3/Dashboard.php#L64 you can set default values, You can also specify the type and even limit to specific options see https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/api/v3/Contribution.php#L552 also https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/api/v3/Contribution.php#L723. Also as per https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/api/v3/Contribution.php#L360 you can specify aliases or alternate field names for legacy or similar handling

Comment: These are useful examples, but what I'm really looking for is a *comprehensive list*, in part because I'd like to write new documentation for on this subject to help other developers in the future.

Comment: Hi Sean i looked around and i struggled to build a comprehensive list for myself, However it seems to do similar things to getFields, So my hunch is that you can put in anything that the xml files would accept, + api.required and api.default to specify if you need the field or not and what the default value of the field is

Comment: Seamus, yeah I had the same thought. But even that rule of thumb doesn't seem "complete" to me because I've also noticed `'api.unique'` and `'api.aliases'`, `'api.filter'`, `'api.return'`, `'description'`, `'FKClassName'`, `'FKApiName'`, `'supports_joins'`, `'options'`, ... yada yada. Personally it's very important to me that documentation be [complete](http://www.writethedocs.org/guide/writing/docs-principles/#complete), so I'm searching for some sort of authoritative way to verify a complete list here.

Comment: Sean i think apart from checking in with the folks in the API channel there really isn't much other documentation on the _spec functions. Eileen probably knows as much as anyone else